# How to configure OpenVPN to set clients to use ISP/router DNS

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I'm trying to setup OpenVPN on my home server to get around the great firewall of China when I'm going to be traveling there in the future (shhh).

From what I have read, the server can push DNS settings to its clients using `push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"`. Will this cause the client to use the Google DNS servers from the client location? (in which case it will be blocked by the great firewall). Or will it tunnel all internet traffic to my US home network and then use google DNS?

I'm trying to set it so that the clients use my US home ISP's dns servers. I tried setting `push "dhcp-option DNS 192.168.1.1"` (where 192.168.1.1 is the ip of my router) and it seemed to work as I can connect to the internet on my client device even using mobile data. I'm not really sure if this is the correct way to do it, because the clients are in the vpn subnet 10.8.x.x, so I'm not sure whether I should supply the ip address of the vpn server in that subnet or the ip address of my router in the "real" 192.168.x.x. subnet (like im doing now).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are absolutely on the right way.

Comment: `Will this cause the client to ... from the client location` - It depends on your routes.  Look at your routing table when connected, perform traceroutes.

Comment: I'm actually interested in this question as well. I tried setting the option to both: `push "dhcp-option DNS 10.8.0.1"` and `push "dhcp-option DNS my-real-ip"` but none of this worked, only when I set something like google's DNS servers then I can actually connect to internet through the VPN.